# Is there a way to specify __device__ for an entire file? (Nvidia Cuda Compiler)

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I am importing a library and I get this error when compiling:

```
go.cu(61): error: calling a __host__ function("TinyJS::Interpreter::Interpreter()") from a __global__ function("capnduk_kernel") is not allowed
```

...is there a way to port an entire file ([TinyJS](https://github.com/gfwilliams/tiny-js/blob/master/TinyJS.cpp)) to run on the device?

I've checked the compiler documentation, and it doesn't look like there's a way to do this. I'm guessing the only way is to rewrite the file by hand, which is a can of worms.

Comment: Nvidias `nvc`/`nvc++` compilers (from the NVHPC Toolkit, based on the old PGI compilers) might be able to make this work as it can determine `__host__` and `__device__` automatically. Are you sure that everything in that file would be valid device code?

Comment: After looking at the linked file, I think it is rather unlikely that this will work with or without `__device__` specifiers. There is a lot of stuff like exceptions that are just not supported in device code. I guess porting a JS interpreter to GPU **is** a can of worms. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm just trying to interpret basic javascript code snippets on the kernel. Even for proof of concept doesn't have to be JavaScript. I found another library, https://mujs.com/index.html – but this faces issues having to be ported from C to C++ and from host to device.

Comment: specifically, I'm having the cuda cores run 1 million variations of the same code, and return the results. It's difficult.

Comment: Why does it have to be ported to C++ first? Nowadays CUDA calls itself a C++ dialect, but I would think that a C implementation is still easier to port as there might be less unsupported things in there. Either way I would be hesitant to bet on this running faster on a GPU without **a lot** of manual optimization if at all. Parsing is just not a workload GPUs are designed for. I would imagine that you will get lots of warp divergence, no coalesced reads from global memory, etc in a naive implementation.

Comment: Your description doesn't sound as if there was a lot of communication going on. So MPI (maybe with OpenMP) on a Cluster should be very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do this with `nvcc`.  It will require manual effort.

Answer (score 0):

While NVCC does not support this (as Robert [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74391883/1593077)), this *is* an option for run-time compilation, via the NVRTC library:

Documentation [lists](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvrtc/index.html#group__options) the following compilation option:

> `--device-as-default-execution-space` (`-default-device`)
>
> Treat entities with no execution space annotation as `__device__` entities.

Notes:

- With this being the case, I would consider submitting a bug report to NVIDIA and asking them to add this option to NVCC.
- clang++ supports compiling CUDA, perhaps it has such a flag.
- This NVRTC is also supported by the [Modern-C++ wrappers library for CUDA](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/), which is [more convenient to use](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/blob/master/examples/modified_cuda_samples/vectorAdd_nvrtc/vectorAdd_nvrtc.cpp#L45) than working with NVRTC directly. (Caveat: That's my own library.)

Comment: So I could potentially make a compiler wrapper that does the work for me?

Comment: @redolent: NVCC doesn't just compile, it drives compilation and linking, host- and device-side, including building stubs for invoking kernels with the triple-chevron syntax, and so on. But, yes, you could. If you want to talk in more detail about what you're trying to achieve you could invite me to a chat or something. Or email me.

Comment: Yes, please reach out to me. I cannot find your contact info

Comment: @redolent: [my web page](https://eyalroz.github.io/) has contact information.